# How crash recovery process works in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, transaction, recovery

I would like to ask a question regarding recovery process while restoring database operation. Let's say I restored a full backup with `NORECOVERY` followed by restoring two t-log backups with `NORECOVERY`. Lastly, I am going to restore the last 3rd t-log backup with `RECOVERY` keyword.

The question is: when I restore the last t-log backup with `RECOVERY` keyword, does SQL Server perform redo as well as undo phases or just does undo phase?

It seems to me that when we restore backup with `NORECOVERY` keyword, SQL Server also performs redo phase. The same thing with restoring t-log backups with standby keyword. In this case, SQL Server creates a separate file with the name that contains only "**undo**" not any "**redo**".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Comparison of RECOVERY and NORECOVERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#comparison-of-recovery-and-norecovery) section of the RESTORE Statements doc should help you with that question:

> Rollback is controlled by the RESTORE statement through the [ RECOVERY
> | NORECOVERY ] options:
>
> - NORECOVERY specifies that rollback doesn't occur. This allows    rollforward to continue with the next statement in the sequence.
>   In this case, the restore sequence can restore other backups and roll    them forward.
> - RECOVERY (the default) indicates that rollback should be performed    after rollforward is completed for the current backup.
>   Recovering the database requires that the entire set of data being    restored (the rollforward set) is consistent with the
>   database. If    the rollforward set has not been rolled forward far
>   enough to be    consistent with the database and RECOVERY is
>   specified, the Database    Engine issues an error.